# Цепочки переполнения в хэш таблице

Tags: массивы, алгоритм, хеширование

Я не понимаю, как возникают коллизии в хэш-таблице и способ их разрешения.
Но у меня есть догадка, что коллизия возникает, когда хэш-функция вычисляет хэш-значение за пределами `int` (то есть максимальное число в `int` - это примерно 2 млрд, а вычислилось, например, 3 млрд).

Вернее, способ я понимаю - это связный список, если возникает коллизия, но как оно внутри работает вообще не понимаю.

Допустим: вот у меня хэш-функция выдала значение 153, потом еще 153, но последнее 153 получилось в результате переполнения числа `int` (в реале, допустим, было примерно 2 млрд 153). Компьютер смотрит одинаково на числа 153 и примерно 2 млрд 153. Но! Меня удивляет, что коллизия всегда разрешается 100% правильно.

То есть в массиве под индексом 153 лежит связный список. Ключ = равен индексу массива. Там есть `key = 153: Masha` и ссылка на следующий элемент `key = 153: Gena`.

Как компьютер понимает, когда ему надо отдать значение `Masha`, а когда `Gena`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Я не понимаю как возникают коллизии в
> хэш таблице и способ их разрешения

Таблица суть есть массив. Массив конечен. Набор значений, которые могут хранится в таблице в общем случае бесконечен, например строки. Примерно как общественный транспорт, кол-во мест в автобусе конечно, а пассажиров нет.

Вспомним определение функции - это правило, по которому элементу из одного множества ставится в соответствии один элемент из другого множества. Здесь же отображается бесконечное множество на конечное. Стало быть, рано или поздно для двух строк будет высчитан один и тот же хэш.

Элемент массива - список. Операция поиска пробегает по списку в поиске уже не хэша, а именно ключа.
Например, в списке по индексу 153 есть (Misha)-(Gena).

Вопрос - есть ли Gena в таблице? Вычисляется хэш от "Gena", результат 153. Бежим по списку в элементе массива 153. Первый элемент списка равен "Gena"? Нет, он равен "Misha". Второй элемент? Да. Ответ - "Gena" в хэш-таблице есть.
Аналогично со вставкой/удалением.

Comment: Точно, нам надо искать по первоначальному Gena или Masha, а я ищу уже по хэш-значению и не понимаю.

Короче, глупый вопрос. 
Спасибо за ответ!

Comment: Вы не так сильно неправы, как думаете. Существует способ разрешения коллизий, когда, в случае коллизии, индекс в массиве высчитывается другой хэш-функцией.